# Swift get data from service in view model

Tags: ios, api, swiftui

Hi I'm a beginner at swift and I'm using a ViewModel and I'm trying to fetch data from an api I've setup locally as follows;

```
//
//  LocationsViewModel.swift
//
//

import Foundation
import MapKit
import SwiftUI

class LocationsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    // all loaded locations
    @Published var locations: [Location]
    
    // Current location on map

    @Published var mapLocation: Location {
        didSet {
            updateMapRegion(location: mapLocation)
        }
    }
    
    // current region on map
    @Published var mapRegion: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion()
    
    // show list of locations
    @Published var showLocationsList: Bool = false
    
    
    // show location detail via sheet
    @Published var sheetLocation: Location? = nil
    
    let mapSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(
        latitudeDelta: 0.1,
        longitudeDelta: 0.1
    )
    
    init() {
     LocationsDataService.fetch()
    let locations = LocationsDataService.locations
    self.locations = locations
    self.mapLocation = locations.first!

    self.updateMapRegion(location: locations.first!)
        
    }
    
    
    private func updateMapRegion(location: Location) {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
            mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(
                center: location.coordinates,
                span: mapSpan
            )
        }
    }
    
    func toggleLocationsList() {
        withAnimation(.spring()) {
            showLocationsList.toggle()
        }
    }
    
    func showNextLocation(location: Location) {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
            mapLocation = location
            showLocationsList = false
        }
    }
    

}
```

However this is throwing me an error on the following two lines;

```
    LocationsDataService.fetch()
    let locations = LocationsDataService.locations
```

Which are;

`Instance member 'fetch' cannot be used on type 'LocationsDataService'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?`

`Instance member 'locations' cannot be used on type 'LocationsDataService'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?`

My data service is as follows;

```
//
//  LocationsDataService.swift
//

import Foundation
import MapKit

class LocationsDataService {
    let token = "2|asOnUG27uCrcVuGxOO65kS25mX0nUSls5ApfemQy";
    @Published var locations: [Location] = []
    
    func fetch() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080/api/locations") else {
            print("Invalid url...")
            return
        }
        var urlRequest = URLRequest( //2
            url: url
        )
        urlRequest.setValue( //3
            "Bearer \(token)",
            forHTTPHeaderField: "Authentication"
        )
        urlRequest.setValue( //4
            "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type"
        )
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { [weak self] data, _, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }

            do {
                let apiLocations = try JSONDecoder().decode([Location].self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.locations = apiLocations
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        
        }
        task.resume()
        
    }
    
}
```

This is my location model;

```
//
//  Location.swift
//
//

import Foundation
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

struct Location: Identifiable, Equatable, Codable {
    
    static func == (lhs: Location, rhs: Location) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    let name: String
    let cityName: String
//    let coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let description: String
    let imageNames: [String]
    let link: String
    var id: String {
        // create computed variable for id
        name + cityName
    }
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double

    var coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(latitude), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(longitude))
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I can fetch the data from the api in my service class and use it in the LocationsViewModel??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `LocationsDataService.fetch()` you are calling static function fetch which doesn't exist. You need an instance of `LocationsDataService`, so basically you need to instantiate it and then call `fetch()` like this

```
let dataService = LocationsDataService()
dataService.fetch()
```

It is the same story with `locations` property.

Otherwise you can make `fetch` and `locations` static on `LocationsDataService` but usually that is something you don't want.

Comment: thanks that's pointed me into the right direction I'll try some stuff and probably have to repost a different question